# Recurrence for the running time of a recursive version of insertion sort

Tags: recurrence-relations

I understand all the steps of the solution until the very last step (highlighted in yellow). It's not clear to me where we substitute equation (5) into.

[image]

Since there were three dots below the 8th equation, I figure there were 3 more equations for a total of 11 equations. I completed the 9th, 10th, and 11th equation. So is the eleventh equation the previous equation it's talking about?

[image]